# AppCenter cannot seem to find Android resources

Tags: android, react-native, visual-studio-app-center

I am building a React-Native mobile app through AppCenter and the Android version is failing in one of the last build steps:

```
> Task :app:processReleaseResources FAILED
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processReleaseResources'.
> Android resource linking failed

/Users/runner/runners/2.166.3/work/1/s/android/app/build/intermediates/merged_manifests/release/AndroidManifest.xml:14: AAPT: error: resource mipmap/ic_launcher (aka org.***.mobile:mipmap/ic_launcher) not found.

  /Users/runner/runners/2.166.3/work/1/s/android/app/build/intermediates/merged_manifests/release/AndroidManifest.xml:14: AAPT: error: resource string/app_name (aka org.***.mobile:string/app_name) not found.

  /Users/runner/runners/2.166.3/work/1/s/android/app/build/intermediates/merged_manifests/release/AndroidManifest.xml:14: AAPT: error: resource mipmap/ic_launcher_round (aka org.***.mobile:mipmap/ic_launcher_round) not found.

  /Users/runner/runners/2.166.3/work/1/s/android/app/build/intermediates/merged_manifests/release/AndroidManifest.xml:14: AAPT: error: resource style/AppTheme (aka org.***.mobile:style/AppTheme) not found.

  /Users/runner/runners/2.166.3/work/1/s/android/app/build/intermediates/merged_manifests/release/AndroidManifest.xml:22: AAPT: error: resource string/app_name (aka org.***.mobile:string/app_name) not found.

  error: failed processing manifest.
```

It is almost like it cannot find the files found in the Android res directory such as strings.xml

Am I missing some setting in the app/build.gradle file that is causing the build process to fail in this fashion?

Comment: hey @perry-hoekstra, were you able to solve this? I am running into the same issue on appcenter

Answer (score 0):

Check your android manifest file, there I think you have deleted the mipmap icon, check if all ic_launcher, apptheme all are their in res folder.

Comment: No, they are all there.

Comment: @PerryHoekstra delete the app build folder and try again